# How to show my layout below the navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation, drawer

I have implemented the navigation drawer following [this](http://www.nkdroid.com/2014/11/Android-Lollipop-Navigation-Drawer-Example-Using-Appcompat-21.html). After adding in my xml the activity is not showing the imageview in center position.
Following is my xml file

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2ba886"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <!--   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff" > -->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/logo_img" 
                />

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is the Imageview layout_gravity option is not comming
Please help..

Comment: The ImageView will align to the upper-left of the FrameLayout by default. Also, you should have an exact measure - e.g. `240dp` - for the `layout_width` of the RelativeLayout for the drawer.

Comment: @MikeM. how to show different views(e.g buttons,textview,edittext) below the navigation drawer of the activity view

Comment: What do you mean by "below"? Toward the bottom of the screen? Or z-ordered behind the drawer?

Comment: @MikeM. refer the image which i have attached..where to add the buttons and imageview in the xml

Comment: If you mean you want them in the grey area behind the drawer, you'd put them in the FrameLayout. FrameLayouts, though, aren't really meant to hold multiple children flexibly, so you might change it, or nest another type of ViewGroup in it.

Comment: I also tried linear/Relative layout but still the view is not showing :(

Comment: Check my answer to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851950/android-how-toggle-with-the-button-in-toolbar-to-open-close-navigation-drawer-wi/29854023#29854023)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it this way

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/actionbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Android"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sitemap"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="About"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Contact Me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

remove list view and set drawer item click manually.

Answer (score 1):

try this : Take image view in linearlayoue and set gravity

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <!--   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff" > -->

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/..."
        android:layout_width="..."
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:orientation="vertical"
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/logo_img" 
                />
</Linearlayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/tab_bar" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

please use this may be helpfull